# Creating new views from array elements, bad practice?

Tags: java, android

I want to display an array of elements like a list inside a scrollView. It seems like people around here are not happy with putting ListViews inside ScrollViews, so I figured I might try and create my own list.

I have some entries (typically not more than 10 entries, entries are around a normal sentence in length) in an array that I want to iterate over, creating a TextView for each entry, so that each entry has it's own TextView. My concern is though that this may be bad practice, or that this kind of operation will simply slow down my application too much.

Am I being to concerned with performance here?

Comment: As long as the number of items and the item layout complexity stays low there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have not to be concerned.

ListView is written to display thousands of elements, by reusing widgets. It's fast to create 10 Widgets and the memory used is neglectable. If all elements fit on one screen your approach will be as fast as an ListView and the memory footprint will be the same.